# django authentication view doesnt work properly

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

When I try to login through the login page of my django project, there is the message `User with this Username already exists.` Here I used my own authentication view:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is None:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/logger/bad_login/')
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/logger/bad_login/')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'logger/login.html', {'form': form})
```

Later I found django stock auth views and forms. But still want to know why my view doesnt work properly.

urls.py of my logger app, which used also for saving data of users activity

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from logger import views


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.logger_view, name='log'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_view, name = 'login'),
    url(r'^bad_login/$', views.bad_login_view, name = 'bad_login'),
)
```

And template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Login {% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<form action="/logger/login/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

LoginForm

```
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password')
```

Comment: Show us the template you're using and your urls.

Comment: Is the LoginForm class your own or Django's built-in class?

Comment: template, urls and form source code added

Comment: are you sure that your are redirected to the correct URL?

Comment: after typing in incorect data view work correctly and redirect to the needed page. What about '/' URL its correct I use it in other blocks of my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a ModelForm and those will only valid if [both the form and the model validation pass](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform).

As you are using the User model, your form does not validate at the model level which is why your view fails.

If you change your login form thus, your view will work as intended:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):  # A normal form, not a model form
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

You might also want to fix your view, so your form errors are displayed correctly, and you are utilizing the form correctly as well:

```
def login_view(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is None:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/logger/bad_login/')
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/logger/bad_login/')
    return render(request, 'logger/login.html', {'form': form})
```